# Angular getting arrays with numbers as keys and assigning them to my variables

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

So I call a rest service that returns to me this array:
[image]

And I want to put these values into my variables and display them. But I'm having problems getting the values.

This is my idea:

```
gettDetail(NR: number, table: any) {
   this.ReceiptInfo(NR).subscribe((RESULT: any) => {
   this.RECEIPTDETAILSDATA = RESULT;
      console.log("DATA IS ", this.DATA); //what you see in screenshot

      const firstnumber = this.RECEIPTDETAILSDATA.DATA["0"];
      this.FIRSTINFO = firstnumber; //FIRSTINFO is decleared in the beginning
    });
}
```

So in the end I want 679 to be the FIRSTINFO, 449 to be the SECONDINFO etc.

Also, as you can see in the screenshot, I get multiple arrays.

So, **how can I loop through all the arrays, get the object I need** (in this case all keys are numbers) **and assign them to my variable** (they are called FIRSTINFO, SECONDINFO ...)

Comment: few clarifications :can there be any number of these arrays?
second, will each of these arrays always have 6 elements?
third, do you need first three numbers from each array into fistinfo,secondinfo,thirdinfo or what?
what is the structure of object that you need? One object per array or what ?

Comment: First: Yes, there can be 10 arrays. Second: Yes, they always have 6 elements. Third: Yes exactly. I need one object per array that has firstinfo, secondinfo and thirdinfo. So example if I have 3 arrays: I would have 3 objects with firstinfo, secondinfo and thirdinfo.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: can you show us your 'Handler' object?

Answer (score 0):

if `this.data` and `RESULT` are equals, try this: `const firstnumber = this.RECEIPTDETAILSDATA.DATA["Target"][0][0];`

Comment: yes you can use this:        `let output = [];  let arrOfObjs = this.RECEIPTDETAILSDATA.DATA.map((arr)=>{
    let obj = {}
    obj.firstInfo = arr[0];
    obj.secondInfo = arr[1];
    obj.thirdInfo = arr[2];
    output.push(obj);
    return obj;
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrOfObjs = this.RECEIPTDETAILSDATA.DATA.map((arr)=>{
    let obj = {}
    obj.firstInfo = arr[0];
    obj.secondInfo = arr[1];
    obj.thirdInfo = arr[2];
    return obj;
});
```

This should give you an array of objects that you desire. Once you have all the objects in the array you can use them the way you want.

Comment: This works but only shows the last array. Is there a way to make a loop of this that goes through all the arrays and adds them. Example: If I had 2 arrays then I would get firstinfo,secondinfo,thirdinfo and again  firstinfo,secondinfo,thirdinfo for the second array (I can see both arrays)

Comment: this would give you an array of objects, one object per array. means if there are 3 arrays then this will give and array of 3 objects each with its own firstInfo, secondInfo and thirdInfo properties.